# Can java variables be an unbounded wildcard?

Tags: java, variables, object, generics

for example, can a variable be something like so:

```
public <? extends Foo> FooExtension = new FooAugmentation();
```

without throwing errors, or is there not an implementation of this?
An example of how this would be useful is like so:

```
public class Human{
    private String localName;
    private <? extends Animal> FavoriteAnimalInstance;
    public Human(String name, <? extends Animal> fav){
        localName=name;
        FavoriteAnimalInstance = fav;
    }
    public <? extends Animal> getFavoriteAnimal(){
    return FavoriteAnimalInstance();
    }
}
```

with the main Code:

```
Public class main{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        Human AnimatedCharacter = new Human('Fry',new Seymour());
        System.out.println(AnimatedCharacter.getFavoriteAnimal().isPetrifiedInDiamondium()? 
        "Not the episode with the dog" : 
        "It's the episode with the dog..");
    }
}
```

Or am I over complicating something that could be done more easily than that?

Comment: What exactly do you think this code would achieve that `private Animal favoriteAnimalInstance;` would not? (Personally, I can see the use of this question when combining two generic types, but not with a single one)

Comment: Why not just use `private Animal FavoriteAnimalInstance;` and `public Human(String name, Animal fav)`? Any class that extends `Animal` will be able to be used there.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz not every animal has the method `isPetrifiedInDiamondium()`.

Comment: Ok, but then your code would also not work, because how would `? extends Animal` somehow allow you to get to `isPetrifieidInDiamondium()` ?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz because the `Seymour` class is an extension of animal, and has that method.

Comment: But your Human does not KNOW it has a Seymor, it only knows it has something that extends Animal. For that you needed `Human<T extends Animal>` , then you could create a `private T animal`, etc.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz but it does know. The return type is whatever type `FavoriteAnimalInstance` is.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's "something that extends Animal", nothing more.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, then what if the code was changed to something such as: `public FavoriteAnimalInstance.getType() getFavoriteAnimal(){`

Comment: That would be Runtime, not compile time. Doesn't work. As I said, declare it fixed, with class Human<T extends Animal>, then you can use T as your animal, etc.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz are there methods that can change return type based on an object?

Comment: No, How could they? At compile time, you don't know which object is in there, so how should the compiler behave? Allow everything? Oh god, that sounds horrible.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz well, the compiler doesn't know much.. I imagine it would be handled the same way as generics would, but dynamically change memory allocation as the type changed.

Comment: I get what you're trying to ask, but generics don't _have_ to be used here. If you know what type of `Animal` you should be expecting at any given time (and you should if you're trying to call class-specific methods on the returned object), why not just forget the generics, have `private Animal FavoriteAnimalInstance` and `public Animal getFavoriteAnimal()`, and cast to the expected type like `((Seymour)AnimatedCharacter.getFavoriteAnimal()).isPetrifiedInDiamondium()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the discussion starts to get out of hand...

Your code, if it was valid, would result in a Human object that had a favorite animal. But the `Human` would have no way of telling the compiler, what specific type of animal it was, since all it knew would be "something that extends `Animal` (or `Animal` itself)".

Effectively, it would be the same as...

```
private Animal animal;
```

Obviously, you don't want want to hard-code your animal there...

```
private Seymore favoriteAnimalInstance;
```

So, the only real "choice" you have, is making the instance of Human know what the favorite animal is...

```
public class Human<A extends Animal> {

   private A favoriteAnimal;

   public A getFavoriteAnimal(){
      return favoriteAnimal;
   }
}

...
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Human<Seymour> fry = new Human<Seymour>();
   // etc.
   boolean petrified = fry.getFavoriteAnimal().isPetrifiedInDiamondium();
}
```

Besides that? Not many choices, since the compiler needs to know the type of the object before you can call methods on it. If the compiler only knows "Animal", then you only have animal methods, even if the actual object during runtime is extremly more complex and has dozens of other methods.

And yes, you could reflection to analyze the object at runtime and call methods, etc. - but trust me, that's not a good idea and it doesn't solve this problem.

Oh, and please start your variable names with lower case, thanks. Also "Instance" is pretty superfluous here, since everything that is not a class, is obviously an instance, so it doesn't actually add anything meaningfull here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re making things complicated when it shouldn’t be, clearly you could just have your object holder as the parent, and it would do the same thing. I know generics are great, but I guess not in this scenario.

Answer (score -2):

You have written public `<? extends foo> FooExtension`. Where is the variable type declaration. `<>` is for generic declaration.

Comment: Although short, it is still an attempt at an answer. Maybe 'short and sweet'? However it would be better to provide the corrected lines (or complete program) as part of the answer.